# EaselJS: AS3 to Javascript conversion: on rollover of MC, gotoAndPlay frame 1 of that MC (Flash Canvas for HTML5)

Tags: javascript, html, flash, canvas, easeljs

This is a Javascript issue, for an HTML5 `canvas` project in Flash.  I'm trying to get movieClip `cta` to act as a button, and once it's moused over to play `this.cta.gotoAndPlay(1);`. I'm using the code from the suggested snippets in Flash Canvas and I'm getting the following error on mouseover: `TypeError: this.cta is undefined` So how do I call `cta` from inside this function?

FYI, the `alert` works in the code below (when the MC is moused over), and `this.cta.gotoAndPlay(1);` works also when placed in the timeline by itself outside of this codeblock.

Here's the javascript flash(canvas) is suggesting in the code snippet.

```
    var frequency = 3;
    stage.enableMouseOver(frequency);
    this.cta.addEventListener("mouseover", fl_MouseOverHandler);

    function fl_MouseOverHandler()
    {
        alert("Moused over");
        this.cta.gotoAndPlay(1);
    }
```

Here's the old AS3.

```
cta.onRollOver = function(){
this.gotoAndPlay("start");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I added `.bind(this)` on the end of `fl_MouseOverHandler` in the `EventListener`. It works for me.

```
var frequency = 100;
stage.enableMouseOver(frequency);

this.cta.addEventListener("mouseover", fl_MouseOverHandler.bind(this));

function fl_MouseOverHandler()
{

   this.cta.gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the binding abilities built into CreateJS, via `on`: `this.cta.on("mouseover", fl_MouseOverHandler, this);`

Comment: @gskinner Ah, cool, thank you. What is binding anyhow and why did I need to bind it? :D

Answer (score -1):

your event listener is not setup properly by the looks of it a mouse event should look like:

```
this.cta.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, fl_MouseOverHandler);
```

unless you are listening to another customEvent then you will need to direct it to where it is listening to for the event.

also just to point out if you are looking at something within the same movieClip as long as it has an instance name in that same movieclip you do not need to put `this` at the start it can just be:

```
cta.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, fl_MouseOverHandler);
```

Comment: Thanks but that's not working either. That looks more like as3 to me than JS, is that JS ? :D

Comment: sorry mate, misunderstood, if you are using Java mouse overs have you tried using the `addMouseListener`?